# webview not loading urls, but it will load data

Tags: android, webview, emulation

I'm using standard addresses like google and facebook, but loadUrl does nothing, it just sits there at a white screen, but if i pipe html into it using loadData, it works fine. Any ideas or tips? I've got it enabling javascript, and I have this call:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            TextView t;
            t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pageTitle);
            t.setText(view.getTitle());
        }
    });
```

Do i need to override anyhting else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you have enabled INTERNET permission in Android manifest file.

Comment: Wow, that should have been obvious... but for some reason it wasn't. Thanks!